# Differential calculus: integrate $\frac{1}{x \log^3 (x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like a step by step description of how to integrate $$\frac{1}{x \log^3 (x)}$$

- I know that the answer is - $\frac{1}{2\log^2(x)}$
- and that the integral of $\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}$ is $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$
- and that the integral of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is $\log(\log(x))$

But I don't see how these are obtained.

Comment: "I know that (...) the integral of $\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}$ is $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ and that the integral of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is $\log(\log(x))$" No, they are not. Did you try differentiating these, just for kicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this problem:$$\int\frac{1}{x\log^3(x)}dx\tag{1}$$we can use the substitution:$$u=\log^3(x)\tag{2}$$$$\therefore \log(x)=u^{\frac{1}{3}}\tag{3}$$which leads to:$$du=3\log^2(x)\times\frac{1}{x}dx$$$$=3(u^{\frac{1}{3}})^2\times\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}}{x}dx$$$$\therefore \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}}\tag{4}$$Now we substitute this into (1) to get:$$\int\frac{1}{x\log^3(x)}dx=\int\frac{1}{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}\times u}du=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{u^{\frac{5}{3}}}du$$$$=\frac{1}{3}\int u^{-\frac{5}{3}}du=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{u^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{-\frac{2}{3}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{u^{\frac{2}{3}}}=-\frac{1}{2\log^2(x)}$$

Comment: Having seen the answer from @TimRaczkowski, I would use that substitution instead - it is much much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Make the substitution $u=\log x$, then $du=\frac1x\,dx$ and the integral becomes $\int u^{-3}\,du$.

Comment: Your substitution is much simpler than the one I proposed :)